# Appending to file with pipes doesn't append, but override

Tags: bash

running:

```
cat .bashrc | sed s/HISTFILESIZE=.*/HISTFILESIZE=10000/ >> .bashrc | echo 'HISTTIMEFORMAT="%F %T "' >> .bashrc
```

I expected .bashrc to be duplicated (using the >> directive)

However, there wasn't any duplication. What is the explanation?

Comment: Reading & writing to a file at the same time is difficult to do right, and what you have here is doing it wrong in a number of ways. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I expected .bashrc to be duplicated (using the >> directive)

The file's contents should get duplicated, yes. `cat` prints the file's contents, `sed` passes it all mostly intact, and the appending redirection makes sure what's printed goes to the end of the file, so there's no partial overlapping between the part being read and the part being written.

```
$ cat test.txt
hello
world
$ cat test.txt
hello
world
new line
hello
world
new line
```

Not that duplicating the contents of your `.bashrc` seems very useful. Also, depending on how the timing works, `cat` might end up re-reading the newly written duplicate part too, resulting in more, at worst unbounded, duplication. This is likely to depend on the file size (among other things), as with a small file `cat` is more likely to be able to read the whole contents and see the EOF before more is written.

That `... >> file | echo ...` pipeline is somewhat nonsensical, as the redirection on the left would override the pipe connecting the two commands, and `echo` doesn't read from its input anyway. It has the additional issue that since the parts of a pipeline are started at the same time, you can't know if the `echo` writes its output before or after the left-hand side runs.

Now, if you happen to be using zsh instead, that changes. With `multios` set, zsh arranges for the output of your `sed` process to go *both* to the pipe, and to the file. But since `echo` doesn't read anything from the pipe (and is likely to finish quickly), when zsh's helper process writes to the pipe, it dies of the SIGPIPE signal, and never gets around to writing to the file. You should see that with something like `seq 10 > foo.txt | true` too, it gives me an empty file.

So, just use `... >> file; echo ...` instead.

If you want to modify a part of the file, `sed -i` might be useful. So:

```
sed -i 's/HISTFILESIZE=.*/HISTFILESIZE=10000/' .bashrc
echo 'HISTTIMEFORMAT="%F %T "' >> .bashrc
```

Comment: `cat .bashrc | something >>.bashrc` is inherently unsafe because of a race condition. If `cat` reads the entire file & sees the end-of-file before the `>>` starts appending to it, everything is fine; but if new lines start being added to the file before `cat` reaches the end, it can start duplicating the duplcate. This can go on forever (or until you run out of disk space), duplicating duplicates of duplicates of duplicates of...

Comment: @GordonDavisson, yeah. Though even at best, it should duplicate the contents once, and to be honest, that seems useless enough already. I think it's likely to "work" (as in duplicate only once) with small files, though. On the system I tried, I consistently get the unbounded loop for a file of 4k lines and 74 kB size, but not on a file half that.